# Edit QML property from application like designer does

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick

My application provides possibility to edit some QML object property at run-time.
Is it possible to show QML property for editing like Qt designer does ?

For example, I have QML file

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
id: circle
color: "red"
border.color: "black"
border.width: 1

/* allow to modificate by user */

opacity: 0.5
width: 16
height: 16
radius: width*0.5
}
```

after creation, I want to allow user in runtime to change some of its property.
Is it possible to use Qt designer classes/plugins/anything to display its property and allow to edit them?

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. :)

Comment: I have found, how in Qt creator it's done: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/4eac04fba059a513bb58703660adf516cd6ce6ac/src/plugins/qmldesigner/components/propertyeditor/propertyeditor.cpp  need to understand is it possible to reuse

Answer (score 2):

You can get the QML item pointer in CPP with the following code

QQuickItem *item = engine.rootObjects().first()->findChild("objectNameHere");

Then, you can walk through its properties with the following code

```
for(int i=0;i<item->metaObject()->propertyCount();++i) {
    // Here you can get the name of the property like
    qDebug() << "Name" << item->metaObject()->property(i).name();
    // Here you can get the type name of the property like
    qDebug() << "Name" << item->metaObject()->property(i).typeName();
    // Here you can check if it's a double type for example, and get the value and, set the value to ZERO again for example
    if(item->metaObject()->property(i).type() == QVariant::DOUBLE) {
    // Get the value
    qDebug() << "Value" << item->property(item->metaObject()->property(i).name()).toDouble();
    // Set the value to ZERO
    item->setProperty(item->metaObject()->property(i).name(), 0.0);    
}
```

Within a few minutes, you can create a generic UI to let modify any object's properties with this approach, i guess

Comment: Yes, In this case I need to implement basic UI controls for different types. But, Qt Creater already has it, so my original question was how to reuse it. Actual, I have already found solution, Its QQmlComponent + setData + qml templates (TextInput { text: backendItem.%1.properties.%2} ) but anyway thanks for reply.